# TypeORM findDescendants yielding unexpected results (it returns itself)

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Consider the following:

```
@Entity()
@Tree('closure-table')
export class Group {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @TreeChildren()
  children: Group[];

  @TreeParent()
  parent: Group;

}
```

and then lets create some groups ...

```
const groupRepo = conn.getRepository(Group)
const parentGroup = new Group()
parentGroup.name = "dogs"
await groupRepo.save(parentGroup)

const childGroup = new Group()
childGroup.name = "puppies";
childGroup.parent = parentGroup;
await groupRepo.save(childGroup)
```

okay, and now try to load the tree:

```
    const groupTreeRepo = conn.getTreeRepository(Group);

    const parent = await groupRepo.findOne(group.id);

    const trees = await groupTreeRepo.findTrees();

    // yields the expected result
    // a single tree `dogs` with `puppies` as child
    console.log('Trees', trees); 

    const children = await groupTreeRepo.findDescendants(parent);

    // yields unexpected results: yields both groups.
    // i only expect this to return the puppy group
    console.log('Children: ', children);
```

Do I have something either (a) misconfigured or (b) am I calling `findDesendants` the wrong way